# Git changes are missing

Tags: git, github, alm

We have committed a change for one file using alm merge request. After one month we have noticed our change is missing.

We tried seeing logs for that file but we don't see our change there as well.

But when we see the logs of commit id 2e02e42d6b5094809295d375150d13238318968d. We can see that our changes got merged properly. 
Git logs of commit id

```
 git log 2e02e42d6b5094809295d375150d13238318968d
commit 2e02e42d6b5094809295d375150d13238318968d
Merge: 9e108526c5 c75d3cc631
Author: Sreekumar Menon <sreekumar.menon@oracle.com>
Date:   Wed Feb 19 11:19:43 2020 -0800

    Merge-Request: 12615 from 'users/amit.tiwary/enh30472668' into 'develop'
```

Git logs of file

```
 git log -p PrePostScripts.xml
commit 1870c07e6b0af5b63f92001f546a58488ee42979
Author: joshua.kesselman <joshua.kesselman@oracle.com>
Date:   Tue Apr 2 13:04:22 2019 -0700
```

Kindly let me know how to check what happened to the commit 2e02e42d6b5094809295d375150d13238318968d.

Comment: Perhaps someone removed the changes later on?

Comment: If that is the case we should see that in logs. Please help me out to check

Comment: Edit your question and show exactly what commands you're using to check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note this in the merge commit:

```
Merge: 9e108526c5 c75d3cc631
```

`9e108526c5` was the HEAD of the `develop` branch when the merge happened, and `c75d3cc631` was the HEAD of the branch that got merged. Start investigating there by doing:

```
git checkout c75d3cc631
```

and investigating the state of the repository. The correct change should exist there. You should now start a bisect to see which commit removed the changes. To start the bisect do:

```
git bisect start
```

Since you're currently in c75d3cc631 and the change is there, mark it as good with:

```
git bisect good
```

Then switch back to HEAD and mark it as bad since the change is missing there:

```
git checkout develop
git bisect bad
```

Git will now automatically checkout a commit in the middle. See if the change is there. If not, do `git bisect bad` and git will continue. Once git checks out a commit where the change does exist, do `git bisect good`. Continue this process until git tells you that it found out which commit was responsible for the problem.

Comment: Hi Nikos - In this case why are the changes done to file "PrePostScripts.xml" are missing.  How it identify the person who overwritten the changes

Comment: @Paul Does `git show 1870c07` display the correct change?

Comment: git show 1870c07
commit 1870c07e6b0af5b63f92001f546a58488ee42979
Author: joshua.kesselman <joshua.kesselman@oracle.com>
Date:   Tue Apr 2 13:04:22 2019 -0700

    BUGID: 29280520
    DESCRIPTION: Callback for delete enitities

    FIX:

    REVIEWER:

    IMPACTED AREA(s):

    TEST CASE(s):

Comment: My question is what happened to the commit 2e02e42d6b5094809295d375150d13238318968d finally

Comment: @Paul What do you mean what happened to it? It's there according to what you posted, and it's just a merge commit. `git show 2e02e42` shouldn't show any changes. Does it?

Comment: It is giving the below output. But my file doesn't contain the changes now which I have noticed after a month.  ```git show 2e02e42
commit 2e02e42d6b5094809295d375150d13238318968d
Merge: 9e108526c5 c75d3cc631
Author: Sreekumar Menon <sreekumar.menon@oracle.com>
Date:   Wed Feb 19 11:19:43 2020 -0800

    Merge-Request: 12615 from 'users/amit.tiwary/enh30472668' into 'develop' ```

Comment: I have used command ``` git log --follow -- PrePostScripts.xml``` that gave me the output ```commit c75d3cc631ff66dd4f7f4b8223d67676b5c543c2 (origin/users/amit.tiwary/enh30472668)
Author: Debadutta Rath <debadutta.rath@oracle.com>
Date:   Tue Feb 18 23:53:27 2020 -0700

    EPMPBCS-16347 Removing TRCS related entries from PrePostScripts.xml of Platform as Enh 30534998 - PROVIDE TRCS SPECIFIC PREANDPO

commit 1870c07e6b0af5b63f92001f546a58488ee42979
Author: joshua.kesselman <joshua.kesselman@oracle.com>
Date:   Tue Apr 2 13:04:22 2019 -0700

``` but the latest change is not existing.

Comment: @Paul Since the merge commit says `Merge: 9e108526c5 c75d3cc631`, I would look up what those commits are. `9e108526c5` was the HEAD in `develop` when the merge happened, and `c75d3cc631` was the HEAD in the branch that was merged.  So start investigating `git show c75d3cc631`.

Comment: @Paul You can also `git checkout c75d3cc631` and see what the state of the repo was at that point. (A `git checkout develop` will then bring you back out again from this detached state.)

Comment: My changes looks good at c75d3cc631 but not sure which commit id or merge id overwritten my changes. I am trying to find that

Comment: @Paul You can now do a git bisect to find out which commit removed the changes. I completely changed my answer with instructions.

Answer (score 0):

In my case one feature branch got merged with develop and over written the changes I have made